# Why don't nested components show in the output of the JSS Layout Service?

Tags: jss

Using the OTB sitecore installation, I wanted to JSS'ify the home node for testing purposes. 
By default this is setup with the following presentation details:

[image]

The steps I followed were to:

1. Update the `sample layout` item to include `main` in the field `Layout Service Placeholders`
2. Create a new placeholder settings item: `centercolumn`
3. Update the `Sample Sublayout` item to include `centercolumn` in the field `Layout Service Placeholders`
4. Added `Sample Inner Sublayout` as an allowed control in the placeholder settings item

The issue I find is that the layout service never includes the rendering information for the `Sample Inner Sublayout`. The placeholder json is always empty:

[image]

Why might this be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, the `jss` named configuration for Layout Service uses the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Placeholders.DynamicPlaceholdersResolver`, so it expects placeholder keys to be dynamic.

If you're managing renderings via Content Editor / presentation details, you either need to manually construct dynamic placeholder keys (yuck, but possible), or in:
`App_Config/Sitecore/LayoutService/Sitecore.LayoutService.Jss.config`

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <layoutService>
      <configurations>
        <config name="jss">
          <rendering type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Configuration.DefaultRenderingConfiguration, Sitecore.LayoutService">
            <!-- change below to SimplePlaceholdersResolver -->
            <placeholdersResolver type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Placeholders.DynamicPlaceholdersResolver, Sitecore.LayoutService" />
```

Change the `<placeholdersResolver />` node to use the built-in `Sitecore.LayoutService.Placeholders.SimplePlaceholdersResolver`. The "simple" resolver allows you to use non-dynamic placeholder keys.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of Dynamic placeholders.
You should put your Inner Sublayout component to placeholder `centercolumn-{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}-0`, GUID stands for parent rendering ID.
However I don't know if Dynamic placeholders are the only option, if it is possible to switch to Static ones and how to configure it via Content Editor. When using Experience editor – these IDs being inserted automatically.

Comment: How would one located the GUID? Would it be feasible for a normal content author?